# Splitting array within array

Tags: c#, regex

I have an array for my KPI system as follow

```
[3374,0,[,,,,,[[18650505,[297688,1,1,500.00,0.00],[0.7,-0.9]],[18650506,[297688,3,1,500.00,7.50],[-0.86,0.6]]],,,0],[[],[],,0],[[],[],[]]]
```

Currently I am use regex to split the array and store in a list, but my regex is not getting what I need, but it is near.

My current regex is [.+?] which will return more what than I need , therefore I have to do additional steps to make it what I need. I feel that is waste of time . Is that any better regex can directly help me to what I need as below

I need only `[18650505,[297688,1,1,500.00,0.00],[0.7,-0.9]` as List[0] and `[18650506,[297688,3,1,500.00,7.50],[-0.86,0.6]` as as List[1].

Comment: you should be able to use a parser in whatever language this is in and not have to reinvent the wheel

Comment: i'm using c# , what parser can parse this array ?? any idea?

Comment: What are rules which determines these particular targets?

Comment: This is is a Fixed [3374,0,[,,,,,[[18650505,[297688,1,1,500.00,0.00],[0.7,-0.9]],[18650506,[297688,3,1,500.00,7.50],[-0.86,0.6]]],,,0],[[],[],,0],[[],[],[]]]

Comment: with always the same numbers or the same place?

Comment: value will be different , but positioning , structure all remain the same always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern that matches the subarrays:

```
[-\d.]*,\[[-\d.]*,[-\d.]*,[-\d.]*,[-\d.]*,[-\d.]*],\[[-\d.]*,[-\d.]*]
```